# Get file name from javascript ES6 class reference in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Is there a way to get the file name from a reference to a class?  Please note this example is over simplified to illustrate what I'm trying to do (don't start suggesting logging libraries please!)

```
//Logger1.js
class Logger1  {

}

//MainProcess.js
class MainProcess {
    startChildProcess(Logger) {
        //This extension doesn't work, but looking to find something similar that does:
        Logger.fileName = () => {
            return __filename
        }

        let loggerFileName = Logger.fileName() //Returns "Main.js" not "Logger1.js", so no good...
        childProcess.fork(processFileName, [loggerFileName] )

    }
}

//In a child process spawned by main: 
loggerPath = process.argv[2]
let Logger = require(loggerPath)[path.basename(loggerPath).replace(".js","")]
let logger = new Logger()
```

I can obviously add a property with a string value, or a method to return __filename the Logger1 class, but I'd rather avoid it.  Is there a way to do this from inside the MainProcess class, keeping Logger1 and any other external code clean?

The reason I don't pass the instance of the logger, is the main process then creates child processes, and these child processes instantiate their own loggers.  And there is no way to pass object references down to child processes as far as I'm aware.

Comment: `__filename` and `__dirname` are specific to node.js, I don't think there is any support in the language, be it javascript or typescript.

Comment: Thanks, yes i need this in nodejs. I will update title to make it clearer.

Comment: You can get the module filename from the module name via require.resolve() - e.g. require.resolve("express") will give you the full path to the Express module - but you need to know the module here and not just a class it exports.

Comment: How many logger classes are there in your application? It seems your real problem is not find the file name of the logger class, but to serialise the settings of your logger instance so that you can pass it to your child process and instantiate a clone there.

Comment: Node's debugger has a way to find the source location of any function (and that debugging API might be accessible somehow), but it's not guaranteed that the filename where the class was defined is also the filename of the module that actually exports the class. You really should add a `Logger1.modulepath = __filename;` line to your logger module.

Comment: Question for @Paul Grimshaw: can we assume that all classes that you want to get filenames for, like `Logger1`, are derived from some common base class and you have control over its constructor code? If yes, I can offer some pretty horrible hack as an answer.

Comment: @artem yes I could force inheritance from a base class, would prefer not too but could be done

Comment: @bergi this is not just for loggers but several dependencies of the app, database connections etc. I am thinking the Logger1.modulepath = __filename is the only way to go, just seems like it shouldn't be necessary as every class will have the same thing.

Comment: Happy with any "hacky" method, as long as it can be hidden away in the MainProcess class

Comment: If anyone can suggest another way of injecting dependencies to a child process I'm all ears...

Comment: @PaulGrimshaw Don't you have one big config file where all dependencies are injected? Why wouldn't the child process be able to use that?

Comment: I'm realeasing this as an NPM package, and the dependencies will be injected by the client using it.  I don't like packages that require a config file to be located in a certain location with a certain shape, as Apps get their config from all different places (we use ZooKeeper for example)

Comment: @PaulGrimshaw what does 'injected by client using it' mean in your example? You have 3 files: `Logger1.js`, `MainProcess.js` and a source file in a child process - which are in your package and which are in the client app code?

Comment: @Bergi MainProcess and child process are in the package, MainProcess will be instantiated and run by the client app code, Logger1.js would in client app code, and injected into MainProcess

Comment: I think i should stop being fussy, the best solution being your `Logger1.modulepath = __filename`